# Find the general solution of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the PDE
$$xu_x+yu_y=x^n$$
Here is what I did
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{x^n}$$
Then 
$$\frac{y}{x}=C_1\qquad u-\frac{x^n}{n}=C_2$$
This is the part I stacked

Is the general solution
$u(x,y)=F(y/x,u-x^n/n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{y}{x}=C_1\qquad u-\frac{x^n}{n}=C_2$$
The general solution expressed on the form of an implicit equation is :
$$\Phi\left(\frac{y}{x}\:,\:u-\frac{x^n}{n}\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

An equivalent form is : $\quad u-\frac{x^n}{n}=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\quad$ where $F$ is any differentiable function.

The explicit form of the general solution is :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{x^n}{n}+F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Comment: How do we get the "equivalent form"?

Comment: In case of implicit equation $\Phi(X,Y)=0$ where $\Phi$ is ANY function of two variables, solving it for one variable leads to ANY function of the other variable. $Y=F(X)$ where $F$ is any function. Or $X=G(Y)$ where $G$ is any function. Of course, $F$ and $G$ are related (inverse functions from one to the other).